# dependencies of grails plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm writing a Grails plugin that depends on the Quartz plugin, i.e. an application that installs my plugin must also install the Quartz plugin. In order to enforce this requirement, I added the following to the plugin's descriptor

```
def dependsOn = [quartz: '0.4.2']
```

However, when I run `grails package-plugin` I get the error

```
Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [quartzJobStats]
- Plugin: quartzJobStats
   - Dependencies:
       ! quartz (Required: 0.4.2, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
```

How am I supposed to specify (plugin) dependencies of a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `dependsOn` in Grails 2.0+, add a dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
plugins {
   build(':release:2.0.4', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.2') {
      export = false
   }
   compile ":quartz:0.4.2"
}
```

or this to use the latest:

```
compile ":quartz:1.0-RC2"
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it's Grails 1.3.7, does the same advice apply?

Comment: Yes, that's valid as of 1.3.x and is important if the plugin will be used by 2.0 apps. You should develop the plugin in 2.x though since otherwise the POM that gets created won't be valid for 2.x apps. Just don't use 2.x features if you also want to support 1.3 users.

Comment: the plugin is only going to be released internally and we don't use 2.0 internally (yet), so supporting 2.x users isn't an issue (yet). Thanks for your help.